# iOS Newsstand push over 3G

Tags: ios, newsstand-kit

are Newsstand push notification being sent over 3G as well?

Or is there a way for the user to avoid downloading large newsstand data when using a cellular network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The device must be on WiFi at the time of the Newsstand push reception. Background downloading will not happen over 3G. I am not sure if such notifications will get queued by iOS for later when connected to WiFi, but most likely it is app's responsibility to Queue.

Comment: But how can be app's responsibility to queue if the push is not received when under 3G? Do you know if there's an official apple word about that?

Comment: Yes you have a point. I think Push is received by iOS but not delivered to app. Another theory could be push received to app but Newsstand framework does not start download if device is connected in 3G (or cancel that download). From Apple's documentation I only found that background download using NS push notification work only in wifi.

Comment: @MSK can you please provide any link where i can find it written over there about this 3G and wiFi thing.